# What can I send to an InputStream to signify EOF has been reached?

Tags: java, bash, sockets, inputstream, eof

In a server app I am listening on a socket and reading using an `InputStreamReader`.

The client is a simple Bash script, in which I do the following to write to the socket and print the output from it:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/9999
echo -e some_text >&3
cat <&3
```

I wold like to indicate EOF after I send my data via `echo`, as-is the java app receives the data sent, but continues to block waiting for more. I need to signal that this one line is the only input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) indicates you do

```
exec 3>&-
```

Found using google. ;)

---

To close on the Java side

```
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: That would be done from the server end. I need the bash shell script to indicate to the server that it's finished sending data.

Comment: On the server we have: while( (input=inputReader.readline())!=null ), I need readLine() to return null, which it does when it encounters EOF. What I'm trying to figure out is how to send it the EOF marker from the Bash shell script.

Comment: This link indicates you do `exec 3>&-` http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html